# How do I increase the space below and above the equations in the cells of the long table

Tags: spacing, longtable

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.7cm}|p{3.6cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{4cm}|}
    \hline
        \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ ABCD  $&\bfseries $ sdf$ \\ \hline \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline 
        \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ TV=P_{n_{1}+n_{2}}  $&\bfseries $ PV $ \\ \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1& &  &$ \dfrac{D_{1}}{(1+K_{r_{1}})} $ \\  
    \hline 
    $x $&& &$ \dfrac{D_{1}}{(1+K_{r_{1}})^{n_{1}}} $ 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also play `\arraystretch` (e.g. `\def\arraystertch{2.0}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard tool (`cellspace`), for some reason, does not work here, but the alternative tool, `\setcellgapes{some value}\makegapedcells}`, from package `makecell` does.

I took the liberty to simplify somewhat your code. In particular, needless to load `amsfonts`  when you load `amssymb`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=1.5cm, vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\setcellgapes{6pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.7cm}|p{3.6cm}|p{2.8cm}| p{4cm} |}
    \hline
        \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ ABCD $&\bfseries $ sdf$ \\ \hline \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
        \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ TV=P_{n_{1}+n_{2}} $&\bfseries $ PV $ \\ \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1& & &$ \dfrac{D_{1}}{(1+K_{r_{1}})} $ \\
    \hline
    $x $&& &$ \dfrac{D_{1}}{(1+K_{r_{1}})^{n_{1}}} $
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Bernard. It worked. But now I want to color my rows. The option \rowcolor{gray} for example is not working. Can you help me please.

Comment: This happens sometimes with `\setcellgapes. I guess it is linked to the fact that `\rowcolor` has to be the very first command in the row. A work around consists in selecting an *ad hoc* cell in the row, and using `\Gape[some length]{cell contents}`.  Namely, for the second row, you select the last cell and code `\Gape[6pt]{$ \dfrac{D_{1}}{(1+K_{r_{1}})} $}`.

Comment: Which error do you have?

Comment: U mean like this:
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.7cm}|p{3.6cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{4cm}|}
 \hline
 \rowcolor{gray} \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ ABCD  $&\bfseries $ sdf$ \\ \hline \hline
 \endfirsthead
 \hline 
 \rowcolor{gray} \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ TV=P_{n_{1}+n_{2}}  $&\bfseries $ PV $ \\ \hline \hline
 \endhead
 \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
 \endfoot
 \hline
 \endlastfoot
 \rowcolor{mintbg}1& &  &\Gape[6pt]{$ \dfrac{D_{1}}{(1+K_{r_{1}})} $}\\ 
 \hline 
\rowcolor{mintbg} $x $&& &\Gape[6pt]{$ \dfrac{D_{1}}{(1+K_{r_{1}})} $}

Comment: The above part of the code is how I wish to color the rows of my table. I have tried to use the \Gape[]{} but Im receiving an error:
Undefined control sequence. \rowcolor{mintbg}1& & &\Gape.
Note that the color mintgb is defined by:
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}

Comment: Did you load `xcolor` with the `[table]` option?

Comment: Yes. By the way is there any way for me to post the whole code so that it becomes easier to spot where i have made mistakes?

Comment: Try to make a small complete code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128033/discussion-between-itc-and-bernard).